# Index Path of Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uibutton

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains two `UIButton`s (An upVote button and a downVote button), and a label that is meant to count the number of votes. I am using the Parse framework for my backend.

I cannot figure out how to associate the value of a particular label with the custom `UITableViewCell` that contains the label so that I can then save it to the Parse backend. How can I reference the `indexPath` of the cell that contains the button using Swift and then associate it with the label so that I can then save it to Parse?

As always, if you feel there is a better way, please share.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Everything can happen in your custom UITableViewCell. The key is to store the parse object as a property of the UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: so you never need to worry about looking up the indexPath. Hook your two UIButtons up and when a button is tapped: update the vote count on the parse object, update the label, save the parse object. Something like this should give you the idea:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyParseData *parseObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *voteCountLabel;

@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (IBAction)upVoteButton:(id)sender {
    self.parseObject.voteCount++;
    [self updateVote];
}

- (IBAction)downVoteButton:(id)sender {
    self.parseObject.voteCount--;
    [self updateVote];
}

- (void)updateVote {
    self.voteCountLabel.text = [self.parseObject.voteCount description];
    [self.parseObject saveInBackground];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but unfortunately I am using swift and am new to IOS. Could you please explain it in terms of swift. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think you created a custom cell to do this. So you have to create two methods in the custom cell class that will handle the touch up inside to its delegate (the tableview controller, for example). When delegate is called, it has a reference to the cell touched and you can go on.

Comment: So should I put the delegate method inside the IBAction of the buttons?

Comment: You have to declare a protocol in your cell interface file. Then, you have to call your delegate into the **IBAction**